# How to create zip files based on Year in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have created an SSIS package which generates the files for Multiple years in YYYYMM format, for example if I set startyear variable to 202001 and Endyear variable to 202101 it will generate the files from Jan-2020 to Jan-2021 in filename_202001(YYYYMM).txt format with the help of For Loop Container. To generate the files Iam calling another package in For loop container. **Now I want to zip the files based on years.**
**Test case is :**
StartYear and Endyear is set to 202012 and 202201. we should see Files with prefixes below in the destination folder .

```
 Filename_2020.zip (one month inside)

 Filename_2021.zip (12 months inside)

 Filename_2022.zip (1 month inside)
```

Please help me with this requirement.

I am trying to use Script Task only, In that I have used two variables which are

1. VarInputFolder (Source folder where files get read)
2. VarOutputFolder (Destination folder where files are generated in a zip format).

As of now I am able to zip the entire folder which is taking a lot of time to do that process because of huge files, but not getting how to zip the files based on file generation years. I am attaching the script task after the for loop container, if I use within the for loop container throwing an exception

```
Public void Main()
{
    string SrcFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::VarInputFolder"].Value.ToString();
    string DestFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::VarOutputFolder"].Value.ToString();
    string DestFile = DestFolderPath + "\\ZippedFile.Zip";
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(SrcFolderPath, DestFile);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: What tool do you intend to use for creating the zip files?

Comment: @billinkc Iam using Microsoft visual studio 2018(SSDT) for creating SSIS packages and I prefer execute process task/Script task  for creating Zip files.

Comment: Right, you're using SSIS to orchestrate the compression of files. If you're using a Script Task, what script are you using and what is the problem with it? If Execute Process Task, what process (winrar/7zip/etc) are you using and what is the problem with the current usage?

Comment: @billinkc Iam trying to use Script Task only, In that i have used two variables which are 1.VarInputFolder(Source folder where files get read) and 2. VarOutputFolder(Destination folder where files are generated in a zip format). As of now iam able to zip the entire folder which is taking a lot of time to do that process because of huge files, **but not getting how to zip the files based on file generation years**. Iam attaching the script task after the for loop container, if i use within the for loop container throwing an exception.

Comment: Logic used in the script task as for sample testing purpose is :             
  **public void Main()
  {
 string SrcFolderPath=Dts.Variables["User::VarInputFolder"].Value.ToString();
string DestFolderPath =Dts.Variables["User::VarOutputFolder"].Value.ToString();
            string DestFile = DestFolderPath + "\\ZippedFile.Zip";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(SrcFolderPath, DestFile);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }**